# Python/Redis Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, redis

I'm using Pool.map from the multiprocessing library to iterate through a large XML file and save word and ngram counts into a set of three redis servers. (which sit completely in memory) But for some reason all 4 cpu cores sit around 60% idle the whole time. The server has plenty of RAM and iotop shows that there is no disk IO happening.

I have 4 python threads and 3 redis servers running as daemons on three different ports. Each Python thread connects to all three servers.

The number of redis operations on each server is well below what it's benchmarked as capable of.

I can't find the bottleneck in this program? What would be likely candidates?

Comment: Accessing the XML file from disk? Inter-process communication with the servers? (What are you using to communicate?).

Comment: The `chunksize` might be too small.

Comment: I'm using cElementTree to parse the XML file and it all fits in memory. Then I'm extracting text from it and passing the words into Redis.

Comment: Is there a lot of overhead in passing each chunk? I didn't manually set a chunksize, but it appears that it's defaulted to 1.

Comment: The `chunksize` isn't about the size of the chunk that's passed (your code controls that), it's about how many items at a time are processed in the iterable that you're mapping. I.e. a `chunksize` > 1 will allow the main process to spend idle time to get a more items from the iterable and cache them for when the next worker process in the pool is ready for one. The downside is that if each item is rather large, you can run into memory issues and/or have a long startup time before the worker threads actually start working.  Try increasing to 10, 100, 1000, up to len(iterable).

Comment: Overheads to context-switching ?  Do-it-all-on-one-box can suffer from that.

Answer (score 7):

Network latency may be contributing to your idle CPU time in your python client application.   If the network latency between client to server is even as little as 2 milliseconds, and you perform 10,000 redis commands, your application must sit idle for at least 20 seconds, regardless of the speed of any other component.

Using multiple python threads can help, but each thread will still go idle when a blocking command is sent to the server.  Unless you have very many threads, they will often synchronize and all block waiting for a response.  Because each thread is connecting to *all* three servers, the chances of this happening are reduced, except when all are blocked waiting for the same server.

*Assuming* you have uniform random distributed access across the servers to service your requests (by hashing on key names to implement sharding or partitioning), then the odds that three random requests will hash to the same redis server is inversely proportional to the number of servers.  For 1 server, 100% of the time you will hash to the same server, for 2 it's 50% of the time, for 3 it's 33% of the time.  What may be happening is that 1/3 of the time, all of your threads are blocked waiting for the same server.  Redis is a single-threaded at handling data operations, so it must process each request one after another.  Your observation that your CPU only reaches 60% utilization agrees with the probability that your requests are all blocked on network latency to the same server.

Continuing the assumption that you are implementing client-side sharding by hashing on key names, you can eliminate the contention between threads by assigning each thread a single server connection, and evaluate the partitioning hash before passing a request to a worker thread.  This will ensure all threads are waiting on *different* network latency.  But there may be an even better improvement by using pipelining.

You can reduce the impact of network latency by using the pipeline feature of [the redis-py module](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py), if you don't need an immediate result from the server.  This may be viable for you, since you are storing the results of data processing into redis, it seems.  To implent this using redis-py, periodically obtain a pipeline handle to an existing redis connection object using the `.pipeline()` method and invoke multiple store commands against that new handle the same as you would for the primary redis.Redis connection object.  Then invoke `.execute()` to block on the replies.  You can get orders of magnitude improvement by using pipelining to batch tens or hundreds of commands together.  Your client thread won't block until you issue the final `.execute()` method on the pipeline handle.

If you apply both changes, and each worker thread communicates to just one server, pipelining multiple commands together (at least 5-10 to see a significant result), you may see greater CPU usage in the client (nearer to 100%).  The cpython GIL will still limit the client to one core, but it sounds like you are already using other cores for the XML parsing by using the multiprocessing module.

There is a [good writeup about pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining) on the redis.io site.

Comment: Yes, and especially if you are wondering about network latency, you can measure the network utilization during the run to see how heavy it is. If you're "thrashing" on that IO, then yes, the pipelining may help with much of that timing & thrashing.